# How do I use try-catch-finally statement here?

Tags: kotlin

The task is:
The function `pepTalk` takes the space traveler’s name in the input (two words separated by a space) and returns a string with their name and a last-minute advice. If the name has an incorrect format, an exception may occur in `pepTalk`.

Fix the code below: correct the call of the function by wrapping it in the try-catch-finally expression.

If all goes well, the variable advice should be equal to the string that is the result of the execution of `pepTalk`.

If an exception occurs when calling the function, advice should contain the message Don't lose the towel, nameless one..

In the final block, write the code that will print `Good luck!`

```
fun pepTalk(name: String): String {
    val array = name.split(" ").toTypedArray()
    val firstName = array[0]
    val secondName = array[1]
    return "Don't lose the towel, traveler $firstName $secondName!"
}   

// do not change the function above        
fun main() {
    val name = readLine()!!
    val advice = pepTalk(name) // fix this function call
    print(advice)        
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try ChatGPT. That's great for doing this kind of homework.

Comment: "Try" the block of code, if there is an error - "catch" it. If non of the previous was triggered, then "else".

Comment: The assignment is bad. You shouldn't catch all exceptions blindly in regular application code. The exact exception type to catch should be specified, and you shouldn't attempt to recover from other exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it by assigning the result of try block to the `val advice` :

```
fun main() {

    val name = readLine()!!

    val advice: String = try {
        pepTalk(name) // fix this function call
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        "Don't lose the towel, nameless one."
    } finally {
        print("Good luck!")
    }

    print(advice)        

}
```

Answer (score -1):

To use the try-catch-finally statement in the given code, you can modify the main() function as follows:

```
fun main() {

    val name = readLine()!!

    val advice: String

    try {
        advice = pepTalk(name) // fix this function call
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        advice = "Don't lose the towel, nameless one."
    } finally {
        print("Good luck!")
    }

    print(advice)

}
```

In this code, the pepTalk() function call is wrapped in a try-catch-finally statement. If an exception occurs, the catch block sets advice to the specified message, and the finally block prints "Good luck!" regardless of whether an exception occurred or not.

Comment: `try {} catch(...) {}` is an expression in Kotlin, thus it can be used to return a result and assign it to an value directly. You can write `val advice: String = try { ... } catch(...) { ... }` instead.